# Per-Cpu utilization

Tags: cpu, multi-core

I have read terms such as per-cpu utilization. Don't we have just one cpu in our machines ?
Also there are two directories cpu0 and cpu1 in the sub-directory /sys/devices/system/cpu ... Do I have two cpus in my machine ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a dual-core Processor,then every core has its temp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have a dual core CPU.  Most modern Processors are at least dual core, where they have 2 processors inside one processor module.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dual (or quad) core is talking about the number of processors on the physical chip.  So you actually DO have two processors in there, but only one physical unit.  Some computers have many chips with many cores each.  Then the number of processors would indeed be chips * cores.

Answer (score 0):

Some of us have two physical processors, but mostly we're talking about **multiple cores** in each processor. This allows true parallel processing, and as such each core must be recognised by the OS so the scheduling and basic resource management parts of the core OS can work properly.